# How to prevent Words losing when knitting to PDF using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I am running into an issue when a long text or a long sentence, I must say, keeps going on and does not enter the next line. My goal is to create a professional PDF file by knitting through Rmarkdown.

An example of my .rmd file is below:

```
---
title: "My work"
author: "It is me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
header-includes:
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{mathtools}
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{lettrine}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{yfonts,color}
- \usepackage {titling}
- \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[C,C]{It is me}
- \fancyfoot[C,C]{Where I do my things}
- \fancyfoot[L,R]{\thepage}
---


{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos= "h")
library("Rfast")
library(MVA)
library(MASS)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(Metrics)
library(Matrix)
library(factoextra)
library(CVTuningCov)
library("moments")
library(caret)
library("boot")

    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

    Below is an snapshot of the the dataset:
    {r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
    attach(dataset)
    kable(head(dataset),booktabs = T,linesep = "") %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "center")


    \textbf{\underline{Question 1:}} 

    (a) Produce a scatter plot matrix which includes the variables $\texttt{cylinders,     
    displacement, horsepower, weight, acceleration, year}$
```

As a result when I knitt into a PDF file, this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uspVA.jpg

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: check the last answer here maybe: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/646

Comment: @bretauv I have seen that post. Thanks!